# Force auto orientation - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I would like to automatically rotate the screen in landscape or portrait mode, even if the user is locked by default on the device...

Is there any way to bypass this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF4TJ.jpg)

Comment: meaning when the app opened?

Comment: I did not understand your question

Comment: when the app start, you want it to be landscape or portrait mode right?

Comment: The entire app is used in portrait mode, but only on the barcode reading screen that I need landscape and portrait mode to switch according to the actual position of the user's device....

But if the user has locked vertical orientation on their device.... the auto rotate mode does not work

Comment: My problem is in that configuration that every cell phone has, to activate or deactivate automatic screen rotation in applications...

Answer (score 1):

You can use`SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations` and use only the orientation required. The below code will set it to be rotated at any orientation.

```
void enableOrientationChange() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
  ]);
}
```

Edit

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
    .then((_) {
      runApp(new MyApp());
    });
}
```

Comment: But if the device has natively locked the rotation ?

Comment: It will work even on that case.

Comment: I couldn't make it work using this way... is there any permission I should check?

Comment: At least not on IOS

Comment: Edited my answer. For iOS please add required orientation in info.plist also

Comment: <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
 <array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
 </array>

It's like this, and it's still not rotating with the option blocked natively by the user... It only works when I disable the portrait orientation block

Comment: in Xcode please enable requires full screen also

Comment: This option is possible to enable when I mark ipad, because my project is only enabled for iphones

Comment: and even activating it didn't work

Comment: by any chance are you using a stateless widget? if yes please switch to stateful widget

Comment: I'm using statefullwidget